# Using multiple Select Where statements on same column

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause

I'm trying to run a php Where command for Mysql but what I want to do is to select 2 values from the same column, so for example:

> reviews_table - id, recipient, poster, review

```
SELECT * FROM reviews_table WHERE recipient = 'business 1' (But also recipient = business 2) LIMIT = 12
```

How can this be acheived properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OR` like

```
SELECT * FROM reviews_table 
WHERE recipient = 'business 1' 
OR recipient = 'business 2'
LIMIT = 12
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the IN clause

```
SELECT * FROM reviews_table 
WHERE recipient IN ('business 1', 'business 2')
LIMIT = 12
```

For such cases.

I recommend the `IN` clause over separate checks using `OR`, because ˛`WHERE` clauses are often composed of several conditions, concatenated with `AND`, and having conditions with `OR` in between them requires care to be taken regarding the braces, not to cause unwanted consequences.

One drawback is you can't use `LIKE '%whatever'` comparisons using `IN`...

Answer (score 0):

Simply use OR :

```
SELECT * FROM reviews_table WHERE recipient = 'business 1' OR recipient = 'business 2' LIMIT = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM `reviews_table`
WHERE `recipient` IN ('business 1','business 2') 
LIMIT = 12
```